# JsonOutput function adds backslashes while converting a private key to json

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a json file with different key value pairs. I am using the function JsonOutput.toJson in groovy to do it.
Say the content is :

```
def private_key = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzx\nyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'


def test = [
    "apiAudienceURL": "https://xyz",
    "apiKey": [
        "type": "service_account",
        "private_key": private_key
    ]
  ]
```

JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(test)) returns:

```
  {
    "apiAudienceURL": "https://xyz",
    "apiKey": {
        "type": "service_account",
        "private_key": " -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzx\\nyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
    }}
```

How do I prevent it from adding extra backslashes in my private key?

Comment: why do you need `prettyPrint`?

Comment: There is no as such requirement other than formatting.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the JsonBuilder class instead

```
def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder(test)
def jsonString = jsonBuilder.toPrettyString()
```

Comment: JsonBuilder class also shows the same behaviour. I have figured out that backslashes are added to make json valid. So we will have to use replace function to replace '\\n' with '\n' to handle this.